# Access a TextView in a RecyclerView from an Activity

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerView that contains a TextView and I want to access that TextView from another activity, by using the normal `findViewById` method as shown below, but I get:

```
NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)'
on a null object reference "ChordName = findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Comment: You must use adapter for ReyclerView. Than, you can use it.

Comment: I do use an adapter, can you show me how please ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: you can only access it from Parent Activity and you would still need to implement an "interface" for that

Comment: I think what you want to do is send the data using intent from your other activity. Can you share your code please?

Comment: No, i want to edit the textview of the recyclerView, and sometimes set their visibility to FALSE.

Comment: That's not recommended because it would lead to nasty memory leak that would happen when your code is trying to access the activity android OS has destroyed for any reason. Besides that you will have very hard to test coupled code. Your implementation sounds bad IMHO.

Comment: Ok I see, that's what I thought. Thank's anyway.